# My Native Sql query is working but Hql did not work

Tags: hibernate

I am using hibernate. I have a list. I use a hql on dao layer. But my list exist none. But i opened show_sql=true. Then native sql is working. Why my native sql is working but hql did not work.

**Hibernate Query**

```
customers = entityManager.createQuery(
                    "SELECT c FROM LoungeCustomerCash c where c.operationDate between :beginDate and :endDate and c.boardingPass.operatingCarrierDesignator= :iataCode ORDER BY c.operationDate DESC")
                    .setParameter("iataCode", iataCode).setParameter("beginDate", beginDate)
                    .setParameter("endDate", endDate).getResultList();
```

**Native Sql query:**

```
select loungecust0_.id as id2_59_, loungecust0_.CREATEDATE as CREATEDATE3_59_, loungecust0_.CREATEUSER as CREATEUSER4_59_, loungecust0_.UPDATEDATE as UPDATEDATE5_59_, loungecust0_.UPDATEUSER as UPDATEUSER6_59_, loungecust0_.VERSION as VERSION7_59_, loungecust0_.BOARDINGPASSID as BOARDINGPASSID14_59_, loungecust0_.customerType as customerType8_59_, loungecust0_.fullName as fullName9_59_, loungecust0_.LOUNGESERVICEID as LOUNGESERVICEID15_59_, loungecust0_.operationDate as operationDate10_59_, loungecust0_.price as price11_59_, loungecust0_.bankName as bankName12_59_ from LNCUSTOMER loungecust0_ cross join LNBOARDINGPASS boardingpa1_ where loungecust0_.service_type='CASH' and loungecust0_.BOARDINGPASSID=boardingpa1_.id and (loungecust0_.operationDate between to_timestamp('23/09/2018 11:09:02,660000000','DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SSXFF')  and to_timestamp('23/12/2018 11:09:02,660000000','DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SSXFF') ) and boardingpa1_.operatingCarrierDesignator='LH' order by loungecust0_.operationDate DESC
```

Comment: Hi, questions are very, very rarely hibernate AND jsf related. In this case it seems to be a pure hibernate thing and not JSF related.

Comment: Use `createSQLQuery` instead of `createQuery`.

Comment: What exactly is the error? "Not working" is extremely vague.

Comment: @SumeshTG ok. i am trying createSQLQuery.

Comment: @coladict no error message. Also my list empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try using overloaded createQuery method that accepts result class as a second argument:

```
List<Customer> customers = entityManager.createQuery("...query ...", Customer.class)
            // set parameters
            .getResultList();
```